# Set active class on ng-click in ui-router

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here's the repo of my project: https://github.com/vipul-verma/naysa

**Problem:**

In navigation.html I have added a controller named navCtrl and also I added activemenu function to set active class on clicked li tag, but when I load the page first active class is applied to li 'about' as it was set at starting point.

But when I click another li tag it first adds a class to currently li tag but then refresh it and adds it back to 'about' li tag.

Please help to make the active class on clicked element.

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: see the git repository i have given the link

Comment: are you changing your code (and approach) in your git repo?

Comment: currently i am stoping the project and creating an old style based project with html page for each page..angular is too much difficult for such small things i will make another project ... where i will change the approach after asking questions on stack..

Comment: in these cases it's a good practice to close or edit the question in order to avoid unnecessary work of those who wanted to help... yesterday I forked your github project and done some modifications...

Comment: can you give me the link of forked repo please

Answer (score 3):

Use [ui-sref-active](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active) directive:

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a href ui-sref="some.state"></a>
</li>
```

It will look at the url and add `active` class to element if state matches current url.

Comment: i don't have states i only have views or casn you give one example in my demo what will be the some.state fro my url links

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add a `mainCtrl` attached to body and listen for `stateChangeSuccess`:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.log("$stateChangeSuccess: "+fromState.name+" > "+toState.name);
        $scope.activeMenu = toState.name;
    });
}])
```

Remove `$scope.activeMenu = 'about';` from `navCtrl`.

P.S.: I noticed that there is a typo in navigation.html, on line 33 you must refer to 'contact' (not 'contacts'):

```
<li ng-class="{active : activeMenu === 'contact'}" ng-click="activeMenu = 'contact'"><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a></li>
```